# php - relative location of the function

Tags: php

I have language file - `lang.php`, and i have function that use it. function located in folder `/func/` (`/func/users.func.php`).

now, i have 2 files that use that function:

1. in the main root: firstFile.php
2. in folder "ajax": ajax/secondFile.php

The problem is the relative location of the function - when firstFile call the function the code to call `lang.php`  is: include `lang.php`.

When secondFile call the function the code to call `lang.php` will be: include `../lang.php`

but i can't write both of them (with an without `../`) in my code...how can i fix it?

(I tried to wrote `./` and I tried to use `$_SERVER` without success...)

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should help. Personally I like to start my code with `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` to ensure that no matter where I am, I'm at a consistent base location. Alternatively, add your document root to the `include_path`.

Comment: "but i can't write both of them" why?

Comment: @Scuzzy , because that's how php works...

Comment: And you are confident about that? Because I'm very certain you can do `include_once('../foo.php');` without issue.

Comment: @Scuzzy - you can't write both include_once('../foo.php'); and include_once('foo.php'); in the same file

Comment: yeah, the proposal was, to use the one in the first file and the other in the second file.

Comment: @Jakumi the file who use "lang.php" is the function: "users.func.php" . both first and second file (which located in different folders) call the same function

Comment: first of all, "users.func.php"  is not a function, it's a file. this causes even more confusion

Comment: An autoloader is nice to have http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, in each file, you know where you are. Few basic methods are mentioned in the comments:

- determine document root and continue from there (works with one document root):

  ```
  require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'lang.inc'
  ```
- use the information about your including file

  ```
  require __DIR__.'/../lang.inc'; // in ajax/secondfile.php
  // or
  require __DIR__.'/lang.inc';    // in firstfile.php
  ```

you possibly want `require_once` because apparently, you include some firstfile from another secondfile or something.

**update**: you would want to apply this strategy *especially in included files*, because their working directory is determined by the calling script

Comment: both files (that located in different folders) call to function: "/func/users.func.php". only the function call the "lang.php" file...

Comment: you should use this strategy in all your in included files.